# MVP pattern. Using multiple view's with GWT's TabPanel

Tags: user-interface, mvp

I need implement a UI where "header" and "footer" always static. i.e. this content(widgets) dont change along application live. In center I have TabPanel.
[image]

So my question: it is normal(according to MVP) to make one Main view with its own presenter, where will be located all this regions(header,footer,center) and for each tab in TabPanel(center) make it own view and presenter? Or better to make one View-presenter pair for header, one view and presenter for footer, and make view\presenter for each tab?

Answer (score 0):

I have a structure like this, i have a simple class with uiBinder to create the structure. header and footers, almost static, can receive some notifications from EventBus (like username change for header).
This class handles the TabPanel, which contains a real View-presenter set for each tab, using deferred loading.

my 2 cents :)